# How to select elements that have a specific data- attribute with jQuery ? Value doesn't matter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to select elements that have a specific data- attribute with jQuery ? The value doesn't matter.

```
<a href="#" data-apple="some value">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</a>
<a href="#" data-orange="some other value">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</a>
<a href="#" data-apple="123 lorem">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</a>
<a href="#" data-apple="ipsum dolor sit">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</a>
<a href="#" data-banana="testing 123">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</a>
```

I want to select all the elements (not just anchors) that have "data-apple" attribute. How to do it? I want to attach an event handler (on click) to each one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **selector** is

```
$("[data-apple]")
```

And you can attach **`onclick`** event this way

```
$("[data-apple]").click(function(){
   console.log("clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('[data-apple]').click(function(){
       console.log('hello');
    })
```

selector is : `$('[data-apple]')`, this will catch all element with **data-apple** attribute